# Run docker container as ec2-user on AWS EC2

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2

I am running docker on AWS EC2 and would like to have docker containers started as user `ec2-user` so any folders created inside the container using the command `mkdir afolder` would be owned by `ec2-user`.

I added `user: ec2-user` to `docker-compose.yml` but docker refuses to start and gives the error:

`Cannot start service web: linux spec user: unable to find user ec2-user: no matching entries in passwd file`.

This is becuase the container does not have user `ec2-user`. I do not want to create `ec2-user` in Dockerfile at build time, that means I have to modify Dockerfile when deploy to a difference server.

What's a better way to solve this problem?

PS: My Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml is setup properly so when running `docker-compose up -d` containers can start as expected.

#### My Dockerfile

```
FROM codemix/yii2-base:2.0.12-apache
#FROM codemix/yii2-base:2.0.11.2-php7-fpm
#FROM codemix/yii2-base:2.0.11.2-hhvm

# Copy the Yii2 specific config apache config
COPY apache2.conf /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

# PHP configuration
COPY php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini

# Composer packages are installed first. This will only add packages
# that are not already in the yii2-base image.
COPY composer.json /var/www/html/
COPY composer.lock /var/www/html/
RUN composer self-update --no-progress && \
    composer install --no-progress

# Copy the working dir to the image's web root
COPY . /var/www/html

# The following directories are .dockerignored to not pollute the docker images
# with local logs and published assets from development. So we need to create
# empty dirs and set right permissions inside the container.
RUN mkdir -p runtime frontend/web/assets backend/web/assets \
    && chown www-data:www-data runtime frontend/web/assets backend/web/assets

# Expose everything under /var/www (vendor + html)
# This is only required for the nginx setup
VOLUME ["/var/www"]
```

#### My docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'
services:

    web:
        container_name: vl 
        build: 
            context: .
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        volumes:
            - ./:/var/www/html/
        links:
            - db

        # For Apache based image:
        ports:
            - "8080:80"

    db:
        image: mysql:5.6
        ports:
            - "8081:3306"
        expose:
            - "3306"
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: secret-root
            MYSQL_DATABASE: web
            MYSQL_USER: web
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: web
        volumes:
            - mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql
volumes:
    mysql_data:

        # Autostart at boottime
        #restart: always
```

Comment: Did you add user ec2-user to DOCKER group on your ec2 node ?

Comment: @Dere0405 Yes. ec2-user is in the following groups: `ec2-user wheel docker`

Comment: And make sure you did reboot after adding ec2-user to docker group

Comment: @Dere0405 Yes. I think the the groups for ec2-user is fine because I can run `docker-compose up -d` no issue.

Comment: Now I see, your web service is expecting to run by container user `ec2-user`, is the launch script hard coded that way?

Comment: Initially I do not have `user: ec2-user` in `docker-compose.yml`. The folders created inside container would be owned by `root`. I want them be owned by `ec2-user` or `www-data` so the folders can be accessible by my web server.

Comment: Probably you need to post your yaml file, my gut feeling is that you need to use the `USER` command to switch the user to run the entry point.

Comment: Added. Appreciate your help!

Comment: add `USER www-data` at the end of your dockerfile and try, this will change the runtime user

Comment: Thanks, I added code to the init script to change folder permission. Everything works now!

Answer (score 1):

You should create a user named ec2-user in containers. 
In docker file should add commands like these

```
RUN groupadd -g 1000 ec2-user && \    
    useradd -u 1000 -g ec2-user -m ec2-user -G docker_env && \   
    usermod -p "*" ec2-user
```

Answer (score 0):

In order for the web server to mkdir under a folder, the folders needs to be owned by `www-data` user. In the php init script, change folder permission using `chown` and `chgrp` worked.